# String Format Date - C# or VB.NET

Tags: .net, string, formatting

Date coming out of a database, need to format as "mm/dd/yy"

```
For Each dr as DataRow in ds.Tables(0).Rows

Response.Write(dr("CreateDate"))

Next
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
string.Format( "{0:MM/dd/yy}", dr("CreateDate") )
```

Edit: If dr("CreateDate") is DBNull, this returns "".

Answer (score 3):

Convert.ToDateTime(dr("CreateDate")).ToShortDate()

See the MSDN docs for other functions available from the DateTime datatype, including custom formats available through the 'ToString' function.

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.Write(DateTime.Parse(dr("CreateDate").ToString()).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

```
((DateTime)dr["CreateDate"]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

// I would also check that it isn't dbnull before doing it though

```
if (! DBNull.Value.Equals(dr["CreateDate"])) // blah blah
```